# manipulating Array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have bellow array object

```
var datasource = [
                  {"Region": "America",
                   "Total_Time_Spent": "10",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
                   "projectname":"Project 1"},
                  {"Region": "America",
                   "Total_Time_Spent": "20",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
                   "projectname":"Project 2"},
                  {"Region": "America",
                   "Total_Time_Spent": "30",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
                   "projectname":"Project 3"},
                  {"Region": "Asia",
                   "Total_Time_Spent": "30",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
                   "projectname":"Project 4"}
                 ]
```

based on the above I'm trying to create bellow array format

```
var Finaldatasource = [
                  {"Region": "America",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
                   "Project 1": "10",
                   "Project 2": "20",
                   "Project 3": "0",
                   "Project 4": "0"},
                  {"Region": "Asia",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
                   "Project 1": "0",
                   "Project 2": "0",
                   "Project 3": "0",
                   "Project 4": "0"}
                  {"Region": "America",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
                   "Project 1": "0",
                   "Project 2": "0",
                   "Project 3": "30",
                   "Project 4": "0"},
                   {"Region": "Asia",
                   "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
                   "Project 1": "0",
                   "Project 2": "0",
                   "Project 3": "0",
                   "Project 4": "30"}
                 ]
```

means first two columns become Region and YearMonth followed by Project names as columns and value will be the hours spent

i have wrote bellow code and im able to get Region and followed by Project names as columns and value will be the hours spent. but how can also include YearMonth column

```
var Finaldatasource = [];

datasource.forEach(entry => {
  let existingRegion = result.find(Region => Region.Region === entry.Region);
  
  if (existingRegion) {
    existingRegion[entry.projectname] = entry.Total_Time_Spent;
  } else {
    let newRegion = { "Region": entry.Region };
    newRegion[entry.projectname] = entry.Total_Time_Spent;
    result.push(newRegion);
  }
});

// Add missing months and set their values to 0
var allMonths = Array.from(new Set(dataarray.map(entry => entry.projectname)));

result.forEach(Region => {
  allMonths.forEach(month => {
    if (!Region.hasOwnProperty(month)) {
      Region[month] = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got what you are looking for.
If you use es6, it can be done simply.

```
var datasource = [
  {"Region": "America",
   "Total_Time_Spent": "10",
   "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
   "projectname":"Project 1"},
  {"Region": "America",
   "Total_Time_Spent": "20",
   "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
   "projectname":"Project 2"},
  {"Region": "America",
   "Total_Time_Spent": "30",
   "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
   "projectname":"Project 3"},
  {"Region": "Asia",
   "Total_Time_Spent": "30",
   "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
   "projectname":"Project 4"}
 ];
 
 var project = {
   "Project 1": "0",
   "Project 2": "0",
   "Project 3": "0",
   "Project 4": "0"
 };
 const newDataSource = datasource.reduce((res, current) => {
    return [
      ...res, 
      {
        "Region": current.Region, 
        "YearMonth": current.YearMonth, 
        ...project,
        [current.projectname]: current.Total_Time_Spent
      }
    ];
 }, []);
 
 console.log(newDataSource)
```

Comment: thanks this work but project name will be dynamic it wont be Project 1 to 4 always we can have project 5,6 etc.. but anyway this works for me. i know how to move on from here. thanks.

Comment: If the project name is dynamic, you can get them at first.

Comment: This looks like a better case for `.map()` instead of `.reduce()` as you're pretty much doing a mapping operation but with reduce at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function `process()` that will compile your data into the desired format:

```js
const datasource = [{
    "Region": "America",
    "Total_Time_Spent": "10",
    "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
    "projectname": "Project 1"
  },
  {
    "Region": "America",
    "Total_Time_Spent": "20",
    "YearMonth": "2023 - October",
    "projectname": "Project 2"
  },
  {
    "Region": "America",
    "Total_Time_Spent": "30",
    "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
    "projectname": "Project 3"
  },
  {
    "Region": "Asia",
    "Total_Time_Spent": "30",
    "YearMonth": "2023 - June",
    "projectname": "Project 4"
  }
]

const proccess = function(input) {
  // start with an object template
  const temp = {
    "Region": null,
    "YearMonth": null
  }
  // add all the project names to the object template as keys with the default value
  Array.from(new Set(input.map(o => o.projectname))).forEach(pn => temp[pn] = "0")
  // define a function that returns a clone of the above template object
  const getObjectTemplate = () => structuredClone(temp)
  
  const results = []
  input.forEach(data => {
    let item = results.find(o => (o.Region === data.Region && o.YearMonth === data.YearMonth))
    const isNew = ("undefined" === typeof item);
    item ??= getObjectTemplate()
    item.Region ??= data.Region
    item.YearMonth ??= data.YearMonth
    item[data.projectname] = data.Total_Time_Spent
    if (isNew)
      results.push(item)
  })

  return results
}

document.querySelector('#op').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(proccess(datasource), null, 1)
```

```html
<pre><code id="op"></code></pre>
```